# In which direction did Noah and Adam pray?

Tags: qiblah

I have been told that bait ul maqdis was first qiblah.

[Where was the first Qibla of Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2034/where-was-the-first-qibla-of-islam)

When a question was asked to Prophet regarding first mosque, Prophet said first mosque to be built was masjid al haram and after 40 years bait al maqdis was built.

> Abu Dhar narrated: I said, "O Allah's Apostle! Which mosque was first built on the surface of the earth?" He said, "Al-Masjid-ul-Haram (in Mecca)." I said, "Which was built next?" He replied "The mosque of Al-Aqsa (in Jerusalem)." I said, "What was the period of construction between the two?" He said, "Forty years." He added, "Wherever (you may be, and) the prayer time becomes due, perform the prayer there, for the best thing is to do so (i.e. to offer the prayers in time)."
>
> Sahih al-Bukhari: Volume 4, Book 55, Hadith Number 585

Since aqsa is not the first mosque, by default it's not the first qiblah and we don't have explicit texts to back up, telling aqsa is first qibla.

Found more evidence that kaaba is lost qibla of bani israel.

> Imaam Ahmad reported in his Musnad (6/134-135) from ‘Aa’ishah that the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said about the People of the Book (Jews and Christians): “They do not envy us for anything as much as they envy us for Yawm al-Jumu’ah (Friday), to which Allaah has guided us and from which they have gone astray, and for the Qiblah to which Allaah has guided us and from which they have gone astray

Was kaaba the original direction of muslims like noah and adam before masjid al aqsa?

Comment: You have answered your question of the question title already. But the 2nd question about the first qiblah of Muslims is already answered in the post you providedl And the quran, the sunnah and the fact that the Mosque of the Prophet had two mihraabs underline that bayt al-Maqdis was the first qiblah for Muslims.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there are any sources which can prove that Adam or Noah faced a certain direction when they used to pray.

Even if Adam or Noah had a place where they used to pray (say a mosque), that **doesn't prove** that whenever they wasn't in that mosque, that they would pray to its direction.

> لِكُلٍّ جَعَلْنَا مِنكُمْ شِرْعَةً وَمِنْهَاجًا
>
> To each of you We prescribed a law and a method.
>
> [Surat Al-Maidah, 48](https://quran.com/5/48)

To pray to the qibla, might not been a law prescribed to all other prophets. We can't draw that conclusion.

According to the answer on the question "[Why do we face the Kiblah when praying?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/17029/15201)":

> We have to face Kaaba for unity of Muslim.

Which I think all believe is the wisdom behind the rule. Now, this might not have been needed for nations before. For instance, considering Adam and his children wasn't that many according to the mufassereen, the rule might not been needed to be prescribed.

### Conclusion

We do not know at all if Noah and Adam even prayed to a certain direction, therefore we cannot draw any conclusions. We can only speculate, and that would of course not give a certain answer.

*If I'd make a realistic guess however - considering what I mentioned above - I do not think they had a qibla or direction to pray to. In the end that is only a guess, and nobody knows except God.*

---

*(If someone has some references with the exact wordings, pointing that Adam and Noah used to pray to a certain direction, please inform me.)*

Comment: Allah **ASSIGNED** kaaba to ibrahim 22:26. Kaaba boundary already existed. Faintly remember kaaba was known to Adam,

Comment: @Preordainment , Could you prove that Kaaba and Qibla is the same thing? As I mentioned just because Kaaba was known to Adam, doesn't mean he prayed to its direction. And then also there are different opinions about the Kaaba and Adam...

Comment: Down-voter: Explain what you think is wrong with the answer.

Comment: the intuition from so many  evidences of bait ul mamur and BaytUllah is that kaaba is  the qibla of Adam, anyway Allah will not ask us what was the qibla of Adam.

Comment: @Preordainment What you mention is not evidence that can prove that Adam prayed to a direction.  "anyway Allah will not ask us what was the qibla of Adam" - Well, I am just answering his question. If you wish to add your own answer, with evidences, then go ahead, I'd like to hear it.